# Terminating unused http connections that are a result of img ng-src

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an iOS and Android app (using ionic/angular)

I have the following situation:

I have a view that basically does this:

```
<div ng-repeat="monitor in monitors">
  <img ng-src = 'http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/videoFeed?id={{monitor}}' />
</div>
```

Each monitor is actually an IP camera and what we are doing here is transmitting live feed as continuous JPG images (multipart/mime).

What therefore happens is the img tag keeps showing new images continuously making it look like a live video feed

The problem I am facing is when we exit the view, it looks like angular still keeps the HTTP connection open and the server keeps the connection open on its side as a result. The server launches an instance of 'videoFeed' per connection, and I can see the instances don't go away even long after (15-20 minutes)  I exit the view.

Is there any possible way to clear out these connections forcibly from the client?

I searched in SO for other such questions and they all talk about HTTP timeouts - which is not relevant in my case, as this is a continuously updating image feed with one image tag and the only time it needs to abort is when we exit the view.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried disabling the cache for that view `<ion-view cache-view="false">` ?

Comment: yes, it's off. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory but no idea if it will work. I am guessing as long your url is pointed at image and that image is being updated the connection will stay open, or re-open when the image changes. So how about when the user leaves the state you remove the list from the dom using ng-if.

so here is how that is achieved.

In the controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
    $scope.inView = true;
})

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(){
    $scope.inView = false;
})
```

In the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="monitor in monitors" ng-if="inView">
  <img ng-src = 'http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/videoFeed?id={{monitor}}' />
</div>
```

can you give that a try and let me know what happens.

Comment: vote up for the thought. I had exactly the same thought. I tried 3 different methods: a) Like you, I first tried ng-if with a flag. That still keeps the connection open at the server (I  really thought this would work). b) Next up I wrote a directive that trapped the '$destroy' event on that tag and when called replaced $element[0].src with another local image. No dice -- connection still open at server. c) I called a $window.close() when the view was exiting. No dice. 

The only way the connection object closes at the server is if I kill the app.

Comment: wow that is intense. well if i find anything else I will update my answer.